# Adding separator to dateTime

Tags: r, datetime, weekday

I have a vector with a date as character

```
x <- "2015-02-01 09:05:23"
```

I want to convert it to a dateTime object

```
x <- as.POSIXct(strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), tz = "GMT")
```

and then "T" as separator between date and time (see [XML Schema](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime)) to get the following output

```
"2015-02-01T09:05:23"
```

How do I get the "T" separator into the string?

Comment: What is `S`? Saturday or Sunday? If you add more details, `format(x, "%Y-%m-%d%a%H:%M:%S")` should work: `"2015-02-01Sun09:05:23"`

Comment: sorry, I had to edit my question! I am not looking for the weekday, but for a sperator

Comment: Then `format(x, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")`: `"2015-02-01T09:05:23"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `format` function to get a character object.

```
x <- "2015-02-01 09:05:23"  
format(as.POSIXct(x, "GMT"), "%FT%T")
#[1] "2015-02-01T09:05:23"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x <- "2015-02-01 09:05:23"
d <- as.POSIXct(strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), tz = "GMT")
w <- substr(weekdays(d),1,1) # 1,1 selects the first letter of the day

y <- paste0(strsplit(as.character(d)," ")[[1]][1],w,strsplit(as.character(d)," ")[[1]][2])

y
[1] "2015-02-01S09:05:23"
```

if you just want to write a `T` :

```
paste0(strsplit(as.character(d)," ")[[1]][1],'T',strsplit(as.character(d)," ")[[1]][2])

[1] "2015-02-01T09:05:23"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the space with T in this case using `gsub`

```
x <- "2015-02-01 09:05:23"
x <- as.POSIXct(strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), tz = "GMT")
gsub(" ", "T", x)

#[1] "2015-02-01T09:05:23"
```

As per @Avinash Raj 's comment using only `sub` would be enough in this case.

```
sub(" ", "T", x)
#[1] "2015-02-01T09:05:23"
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj yes, you are right. Didn't know the difference between the two. Googled it. Thanks. Updated the answer.